# ESP8266 Stops Working if I don't provide Wifi during specifc step

Tags: esp8266

To test the WiFi connection I'm sharing the WiFi of my cellphone.

If I stop the WiFi sharing during the command below, the ESP8266 stops working.
It only works if I do a hardware reset.

If I don't stop the WiFi it works normally.

```
    if(client->POST(urlCal, host, payload))
  { RetornoPost = client->getResponseBody(); }
```

- HTTPS Redirect (Version 2.0)
- ESP8266 library version 2.4.2

Does anyone know why ESP8266 stops working?

Comment: you forgot to ask a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "stops working" you mean it doesn't do whatever follows the `client->POST` method invocation, then your interpretation is correct and you could have found my [very same information](https://github.com/electronicsguy/ESP8266/issues/64) if you had read the open issues on the library **before** submitting your own.

If I were the author of the library I would be upset by such behavior.

Comment: Now it is working! In tests the version "2.5.0-beta2" solves this issue!

Comment: Sorry for the wrong information, but unfortunately, the error keeps occurring with "2.5.0-beta2". Sometimes ESP8826 restart when there is an error and is OK. But other times ESP88266 breaks, and I have to do a Hardware Reset.

Comment: ESP8266 library version 2.6.3, and watchdog to wait the resposnse, solve this error.